# How to pass function to other components in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I have the following snack:
https://snack.expo.io/@sj458147/rewrite39

The App.js imports StepOne, StepTwo, StepThree, StepFour, and MyScrollView. Within this I want to make the function moveToPage from MyScrollView accessible to the components StepOne, StepTwo, StepThree and StepFour how can I achieve this? I have tried to use props (following various React tutorials) without success. Is using props the best way to achieve this, are there any pitfalls to this approach? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue that you are having is that you are not getting a reference to the your instance of `MyScrollView` so you cannot access the functions that are in it

If you add the following to your `MyScrollView` component, this will allow you to pass the reference back as the prop `onRef`

```
componentDidMount () {
  // this creates the reference when the component mounts
  if (this.props.onRef) {
    this.props.onRef(this);
  }
}

componentWillUnmount () {
  // this removes the reference when the component unmounts 
  if (this.props.onRef) {
    this.props.onRef(undefined);
  }
}
```

You can then use the `onRef` prop as follows

```
<MyScrollView
  onRef={ref => {this.scrollView = ref}}>
  <StepOne next={()=> this.scrollView.moveToPage(2)}/> // you may wish to add a protection to make sure that this.scrollView is not null.
  <StepTwo />
  <StepThree />
  <StepFour />
</MyScrollView>
```

You can see it working in this updated snack

https://snack.expo.io/@andypandy/creating-onref-prop-for-custom-scrollview

Comment: Thank you for your help, works great. I also want to pass the same function to a child of a child. I have anther snack: 

https://snack.expo.io/@drc83/creating-onref-prop-for-custom-scrollview

Would you be able to guide me how I can make the same function available to SliderEntry.js. Currently when the image carousel appears, and then an image is clicked I get an error accessing moveToPage. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can pass anything in props,if the second component is child of first.

```
_myFunction(val){} //do something
render(){
        return(
                <Second ABC={(val)=> this._myFunction(val) } /> //here the props name is ABC
        )
 }
```

and you can use it in child like this:

```
this.props.ABC("ANYTHING_YOU_WANT_TO_PASS")
```